# Can connect to database but nothing happens

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have just uploaded my website to meebox (webhotel), where I have a mysql database through phpmyadmin. The database connection file is working. There is a connection but I get NO data from the database which I have stored.

Here is my php script, where I want to get some data.

The script worked on my localhost server. But I just can't find the error. Is the script too old?

```
            <?php

                $q = "SELECT * FROM journals ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
                $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

                while($journal_list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { ?>

                <div class="col-md-6 journal-list">    
                    <a href="journalview.php?id=<?php echo $journal_list['id']; ?>">
                        <img class="journal-list-img" src="<?php echo $journal_list['image']; ´?>">
                    </a>     
                </div>


            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: check your php version using `phpinfo();` function and write it back here.
if your PHP Version < 5 it might be because you are using mysqli instead of the OLD mysql functions.

Comment: PHP Version 5.5.17    Here it is

Comment: check if the `mysqli_query` return value is FALSE. and print the errors and write it back here.`if ($r === FALSE) {echo mysqli_error ( $dbc );} `

Comment: How do you know the database connection is working?

Comment: It printet out this.  No database selected

Comment: Here is my db connection file.

Comment: <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";

// Create connection
$dbc = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$dbc) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>

Comment: @user2231285 i've added an answer, if it helps you please accept it.

Comment: Checking `if (!$dbc)` will **never** work. You can either enable exceptions in *mysqli* by using `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)` before creating the connection or check `$dbc->connect_errno` / `$dbc->connect_error` as seen in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.construct.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the 4th parameter, DB.

Just set a variable `$db` with the desired DB and try it like this:

```
$servername = "localhost"; 
$username = "xxxx"; 
$password = "xxxx";
$db = "database_to_use";

$dbc = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db)
if ($dbc->connect_errno) {
    exit($dbc->connect_error);
}
```

unlike the old mysql_ extension where we had to do

```
mysql_select_db(...)
```

it can now be done within one line.

Comment: The website crashed, saying. Connection failed: Access denied for user 'xxx'@'xx.xx.xx.xxx' to database 'xxxx'      Hmmmm.  think i have to contact my webhotel. It should work

Comment: Well, it should work, yes. The code is definatelly correct. Do you have shell access? Or another user account with rights on the DB

Comment: That is why i love you guys in this forum.  THANKS you so much. Created a new user and somehow it worked!!!

Comment: You **cannot** simply check the *truthiness* of the object returned from `mysqli_connect()`, it will **always** be *thruthy*

Comment: @Phil, you're right, I just copied it from OPs question and didn't have a deeper look on it. Edited it. Though I think that's not a reason to downvote an answer, a simple comment would have been enough...

Comment: That (`or die`) still won't work as it's the exact same logic.

Comment: See [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790847/can-connect-to-database-but-nothing-happens#comment42159509_26790847) or the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: It's amazing, thank you. I use that $dbc->connect_errno every time in my own program... Well, I guess it's time to sleep, it's half past 1 am in Italy...

Comment: Again, try reading the actual manual. `connect_errno` will **always** be set. A non-zero value indicates an error

Comment: `echo $dbc->error` is hardly going to stop later scripts from attempting to use the connection. You need to stop execution somehow or otherwise bring attention to the *exceptional* circumstances

Comment: Do you mean something like exit();? Why don't you just tell what's the right way?